# Bitwise XOR java long

Tags: java, long-integer, xor

I am using Oracle Java 7.51 on Ubuntu 12.04, and trying to do this

```
long a = 0x0000000080000001 ^ 0x4065DE839A6F89EEL;
System.out.println("result "+ Long.toHexString(a));

Output: result bf9a217c1a6f89ef
```

But I was expecting result to be `4065de831a6f89ef`, since ^ operator is a bitwise XOR in Java. Which part of Java specification am I reading wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need an `L` at the end of the first integer literal:

```
long a = 0x0000000080000001L ^ 0x4065DE839A6F89EEL;
```

Otherwise it is an `int` literal, not a `long` (the leading zeroes being ignored). The `^` operator then promotes the first operand value from 0x80000001 to a `long`, but since the sign bit is set, the result of the promotion is 0xFFFFFFFF80000001L.

Comment: Thank you, for the explanation. Since Eclipse was not flagging me for not putting a trailing L in the first literal value, I was thinking I am in green.

Comment: @Soham - Yeah, you have to be careful about those leading zeros; they mean more to us humans than they do to the Java compiler :)